# ASP.NET membership provider implementation in 3-tier architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a 3-tier asp.net mvc project and want to build a custom provider for user authentication and authorization based on the default one provided by asp.net. At which tier should the membership provider be implemented?

We currently have a web tier, web service tier and a database tier. The two options I have come up with so far are:

1. Implement the provider in the web tier. The implementation will call methods exposed by the web service which in turn talks to the database.
2. Implement the provider in the web service tier. The implementation will talk to the database directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web Tier will be the ideal place to implement membership provider, if you are planning to have only one UI which consumes your services.

Comment: Is it a common practice to have the provider call a web service rather than work directly against a database? What if down the road we plan to have multiple web interfaces accessing the same membership data?

Comment: What you are referring to is to have a Security Token Service or STS, if you are planning to rollout authentication and authorization for multiple apps, yes you are right. But if its just one app having a STS will be an overhead